# Simple Video in webView and memory consumption

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, video

when playing a video inside a webview and looking at instruments - I see a high peak of memory usage when playing. (Around 23 MB in total)

As I leave the view (it is in a UINavigation view) all memory get cleared as it should. (using ARC)

**IMPORTANT**: I am loading the video from DISK and not loading it from server!

**Question:** Is there a way to reduce the memory when playing the video?

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil]; 
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache]; 
//

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: videoURL cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval: 10.0];  
[webView loadRequest: request];  
[webView setOpaque:NO];
```

[image]

Comment: How large is the video file? What codec are you using?

Comment: mp4 format, different codecs (at each time there is a different video loaded thus codec may change) , the size is anything from 4mb to 20mb per video file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it seems to me that you are trying to use an UIWebView as a video player, without displaying any other HTML content in it at the same time.

Even though this is quite possible, it is, as you have observed, not particularly efficient - a UIWebView will load all of it's content into memory since it was made for displaying web pages.

A better solution would be to use Apple's [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952) framework, namely [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009269) and/or [`MPMoviePlayerViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953).

If you only need to playback **fullscreen video**, you should use [`MPMoviePlayerViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009269). Using it is simple:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *vc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:vc];
[vc release];
```

This will present a modal view controller containing your clip.
If you want to customize any part of it, you can use the `moviePlayer` property.

If you would rather display video **inside another view**, you should look into [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953).
Using this class involves more boilerplate, but also gives you more control:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
player.view.frame = contentView.bounds; //The Player View's Frame must match the Parent View's
// ...
[player play];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, nevertheless I am referring to memory usage which is more or less the same while using MediaPlayer. I have tried both and still memory consumption is very high (20MB when playing)